# Variables globales en plantillas de Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

He buscado mucho en internet, tanto en Español como en Inglés y no encuentro la manera.

Quisiera pasar una variable global (no importa si es de sistema o creada por mi) a la plantilla base de django. Vengo de PHP usando Laravel y allí creo un *composerView* y cargo las variables genéricas que necesito mostrar y éstas se muestran en todas las plantillas que quiero que se muestren sin tener que enviarlas en cada *render*.

¿Hay alguna forma de pasar ese tipo de variables que no sea cuando se carga la visa de una url?

Comment: Te refieres a definir una variable que esté disponible en el template sin tener que pasarla en el contexto en cada render?

Comment: @CésarGonzález exacto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear un [Context Processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors). De manera muy resumida deberías hacer lo siguiente:

- Crea la variable en tu settings:

```
VARIABLE_GLOBAL = 'valor'
```

- Genera tu context processor por ejemplo en /myapp/contextprocessors/globales.py:

```
from django.conf import settings

def globales(request):
    return {'global': settings.VARIABLE_GLOBAL}
```

- Registramos el context processor en el settings de la aplicación:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            # ...
            'context_processors': [
                # ...
                'myapp.contextprocessors.globales',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

- En tu views pasas de usar Context a RequestContext:

```
# from django.template import Context
from django.template import RequestContext
```

- Finalmente en la vista utilizamos ese RequestContext en lugar del Context:

```
# context = Context(diccionario_del_contexto)
context = RequestContext(request, diccionario_del_contexto)
```

De esta manera en tu vista deberías poder acceder a la variable simplemente con:

```
<h1>{{global}}</h1>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda